# Insert empty value in CHAR, SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to create a table with an attribute(which is a primary key) that allows only a **CHAR(9) or an EMPTY VALUE** (Empty string ' ') like the following:

```
create table person(
 number CHAR (9) CHECK (number SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}' OR number LIKE '_%')
  );
```

Also i have tried it with **SIMILAR TO** for both conditions

```
create table person(
     number CHAR (9) CHECK (number SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}' OR number SIMILAR TO '_%')
      );
```

but both ways are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is one of these what you want?

```
col CHAR(9) CHECK (col SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}' OR col = '')
col CHAR(9) CHECK (col SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}' OR col IS NULL)
```

("number" is a horrible name for a string value.)

Because you have declared the column as a `CHAR()` you need slots for all the characters.  There are 9 characters in your pattern.  I'm not sure what "empty value" means, but either all spaces or `NULL` seems reasonable.  Because a `CHAR()` value has a fixed length, an empty string (`''`) is padded with spaces to the full length.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `OR trim(col) = ''`?

Comment: ohhh your right .. the char(9) because of the dash. i used number as CHAR so that i can apply the constraint to get like this format (xx-xxxxxx), and what i mean by empty value is like this (' ') or empty string as they call it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . `char()` data types pad strings to the correct length.  I actually tested that logic in Postgres before answering.

Comment: Exactly. and if it's padded then it won't ever be `''` would it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . When I tried it out, it seemed that the `''` was padded to match the length of the `char()`.  Perhaps my test wasn't accurate, but it did work.